# How to add Ctags support to Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I want to provide tags overview in my app, and I want to use Ctags for this.

I downloaded [Ctags](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/) source package and built it. Now, how to add it to the existing Xcode project?

Or, maybe, some alternatives of Ctags exists for Xcode/Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a script that runs `ctags` across your source as a *build phases* step.

You don't mention how you want to view the output from `ctags` though?

Comment: I expect to realize something like Symbol Navigator in Xcode using ctags output.

Comment: No, `ctags` won't integrate with the rest of the IDE.

Comment: Little misunderstanding - I want to realize it not in Xcod, but in my app.

I never worked with `ctags` later, but if I understand correctly, it can create file with tags used in target file, is it?

Comment: @Akki Yeah that's correct.  Sounds like you're going to need to generate the tags file into the app bundle...

Comment: Yes, you're right. For example, I'll open the html-file in my app and see a tree, consisting of tags and describes the structure of this file.

Comment: @Akki But I'm guessing your app will be better off reading the *normal* tags file? http://ctags.sourceforge.net/FORMAT